# How to check if a dataframe contains a string in python?

Tags: python, pandas

My report.txt contains

```
I am a student from Tribhuwan university
```

whereas my dictionary.txt contains this. 
[image]

I am trying to check if the words in the dictionary contain the words in the report. However, using the code below I get the result v as True for only the first element. Whereas, in my opinion, v should be true for all cases as all the words in the dictionary are contained in the report. Please help me figure out what am I doing wrong.

My `dictionary.txt` contains this

```
words, synonyms
I, me
student, pupil
tribhuwan,
university, school
```

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

report = pd.read_csv("report.txt", header=None)
dict = pd.read_csv("dictionary.txt")

for report in report[0]:
v = []
for word in dict['words']:
    if word in report[0]:
        v.append(True)
    else:
        v.append(False)
```

Comment: you can try `report['column_name'].isin(dict['words'])`

Comment: Why not to use `df['column'].str.contains("string")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an explicit `for` loop here. With Pandas, you can add an extra column to a dataframe and use `pd.Series.isin`. You probably also need to make all letters lowercase for comparison. Finally, *never* shadow a built-in, i.e. don't use `dict` for a variable name.

Here's a demo:

```
from io import StringIO

report = StringIO("""I am a student from Tribhuwan university
""")

dictionary = StringIO("""words, synonyms
I, me
student, pupil
tribhuwan,
university, school""")

df_report = pd.read_csv(report, header=None)
df_dict = pd.read_csv(dictionary)

words = df_report[0].str.lower().iat[0].split()

df_dict['check'] = df_dict['words'].str.lower().isin(words)

print(df_dict)

        words  synonyms  check
0           I        me   True
1     student     pupil   True
2   tribhuwan       NaN   True
3  university    school   True
```

Comment: this is indeed nice one +1

Comment: @jpp, This definitely solves what I want to do. Thank you for this. However, I am still thinking why the for loop did not work.

Comment: @pari, first problem is that `dict['words']` is a series not a list of words.